# Batch changing bit and sample rate

Tags: bitrate, sample-rate, downsampling, batch-processing

Here's something I never thought I'd do here... ask a question related to my day job. :D

I'm a technician in a nursing simulation lab -- I get to play with human simulators all day -- and I've convinced the director to purchase better vocal sounds for the mannequins.  We went with [Partners in Ryhme's Human Sound Effects](http://www.partnersinrhyme.com/wmcstore/WMCshop.cgi?action=dbview&id=RSFX03) because the library fit our needs perfectly, and now that I've copied the WAVs onto our equipment, they're making the mannequins crash on playback.

The best I can tell is it's a problem with either the bit rate (705kbps vs the original's 352) or the sample rate (44kHz vs 22), so I need to batch-process 445 files to get the new files to match up with the existing files.

The problem is I don't know how to do that... I know how to do it one-by-one, but that'll take me all day.

Do any of you know of a cheap or free program that I can do this with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITunes will resample all files brought in to it.  Change the input settings and copy to folder to what you need, and it should do it for you.

I know you can batch process sample rate conversions in Adobe Audition as well, but that is not that cheap ($350).

Comment: Luckily, I already have Audition at home.  I'll try the iTunes method first, and if that doesn't work, I'll do it in Audition.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Audition/3.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7de5.html here is the help section for batch processing in Audition.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished creating a consolidated Sound Effects database of over 77000 assets last year.  The files came in all mismatched with various file types and sample rates.  I highly recommend BarbaBatch. It is fairly cheap, super fast, and it accepts and creates all types of variations of file types that many programs don't, like lower bit rates and sample rates.

It will even convert files within subfolders and create a mirror hierarchy of subfolders with the converted elements.  I literally would drop the folder full of folders and crazy mismatch assets from the server and go to lunch.  I would return with a complete copy of my files, extension names replaced without error, and situated in a mirrored hierachy of subfolders in my new specified location. Two thumbs up for Barba Batch!  I think it has a trial download too.

Comment: Ooooh, I forgot about BarbaBatch. Good Call. *not that he needs anything this complex, but a good reference for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

[Reaper DAW](http://reaper.fm/) has a native batch processing utility and it's a pro level app compared to iTunes. (The trial is unlimited use, full functionality and if you want to buy it the license is quite affordable compared to other DAW's). It's also dead simple to use.

If you need instructions then let me know.

Comment: Also good to know.  I keep meaning to try Reaper, but every time I download the trial, something comes up for the next 29 days. :p

For this particular instance, iTunes will be fine -- the speaker it's playing out of is hardly good quality.

Comment: That's the nag screen reminder that you're using a trial. In theory, you can use it for years as long as you don't mind clicking that away every time you launch it. They don't believe in enforcing DRM and trust you'll do the right thing. In all honesty, the software is worth it and supported. I won't even touch Pro Tools for music anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.monkey-tools.com/soundgrinder/